# how can i add a timeout function to javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('spinner');
});
```

and i want to add a timeout function to it i added it like this but it does not work, any ideas why?

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('spinner');
   setTimeout(function() {
       $this.button('reset');
   }, 8000);

});
```

Comment: `$this` is never defined.

Comment: You can put this in a variable so it is in scope of the timeout function, like this: $('.btn').click(function() {
  var target = $(this);
  target.addClass('bg');
  setTimeout(function(){
    target.removeClass('bg');
  }, 3000);
});

Comment: thx honsa :) work perfect